# Proof of arithmetic mean of a sequence given the limit of the sequence

Tags: analysis

Prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=c$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n=c$ where $A_n$ is the arithmetic mean of the first $n$ of $a_n$.
I was only able to prove that is true for a sequence of $1$.

Comment: $(A_n) $  is called Cesaro sequence.

Comment: It is... sincerely I could not understand the answers of that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$A_n
=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$
so
$A_n-c
=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-c)
$.

Since
$a_i \to c$,
for any $\epsilon > 0$
there is a
$n(\epsilon)$
such that
$i > n(\epsilon)
\implies |a_i-c| < \epsilon$.

We now split the sum in
$A_n$ into
an initial "bad" part 
and a final "good" part.
In the bad part,
the $a_i$ are not close to $c$;
in the good part they are.
The key is that,
for any $\epsilon$,
 there are only
a finite number in the bad part,
while the good part
can grow arbitrarily large,
overwhelming the bad part.

To be precise:

$\begin{array}\\
|A_n-c|
&=|\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-c)|\\
&\le\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i-c|\\
&\le\frac1{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n(\epsilon)} |a_i-c|+\sum_{i=n(\epsilon)+1}^n |a_i-c|)\\
&=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n(\epsilon)} |a_i-c|+\frac1{n}\sum_{i=n(\epsilon)+1}^n |a_i-c|\\
&\le\frac1{n}n(\epsilon)\max |a_i-c|_{i=1}^{n(\epsilon)}+\frac1{n}\sum_{i=n(\epsilon)+1}^n \epsilon\\
&\le\epsilon+\epsilon
\qquad\text{for } n > \dfrac{n(\epsilon)\max |a_i-c|_{i=1}^{n(\epsilon)}}{\epsilon}\\
&\le 2\epsilon
\qquad\text{for all large enough } n\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
The fact that the bound is
$2\epsilon$ instead of
$\epsilon$
does not matter.
Any constant multiple of
$\epsilon$ will do.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Let $\epsilon>0$ .
for large enough $n$,
put $b_n=a_n-c $.

$$A_n-c=\frac{b_1+b_2+...+b_N}{n}+\frac {b_{N+1}+...+b_n}{n}$$

where $N $ is such that for $n>N$,

$|b_n|<\epsilon.$

thus

$$|A_n-c|<u_n+\frac{n-N}{n}\epsilon $$
$$<u_n+\epsilon $$

observe that $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=0$.

Comment: Essentially the same as mine, but informal and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then by the hypothesis there is a natural number $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$. Let $K = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_n$. Then for $n > N$, we have
$$\frac{K + (n - N)(c - \epsilon)}{n} < \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_n < \frac{K + (n - N)(c + \epsilon)}{n},$$
so we have
$$\left\lvert c - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_n \right\rvert < \left|\frac{cN - K}{n}\right| + \left| \frac{(n-N)\epsilon}{n}\right|$$
by the triangle inequality. Now, the left fraction has constant numerator and thus is less than $\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. The right fraction is always less than $\epsilon$. Thus for sufficiently large $n$ the right hand side of the expression is less than $2\epsilon$, and therefore the arithmetic mean also converges to $c$.